# Webservice ignores cultureinfo settings of application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I have a webapplication with some forms which are posted to a webservice-method. The json-post is done by the jquery $.ajax method. Although my cultureinfo is set to nl-NL, my webmethod throws an error "10,00 is not a valid value for Decimal.", when posting the values of my form. The same goes for datetimes which have a dutch notation.

It seems like the .net serializer ignores the global culture settings. When i change '10,00' to '10.00' the post is accepted by the webmethod.

We've been struggling with this subject for a while now, couldn't find anything usefull on SO and Google myself. So any help on this matter would be very nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically this is done due this peace of code:

```
// No exponent, may or may not have a decimal (if it doesn't it couldn't be parsed into Int32/64)
            decimal dec;
            if (decimal.TryParse(input, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out dec)) {
                // NumberStyles.Number: AllowLeadingWhite, AllowTrailingWhite, AllowLeadingSign,
                //                      AllowTrailingSign, AllowDecimalPoint, AllowThousands
                return dec;
            }
```

Reference: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/Script/Serialization/JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.cs,111a17298608ded3,references

So the only option is to replace the , with the . and surrender to the English supremacy.

Comment: I'd argue that it's less "surrender to the English supremacy" and more "use the invariant culture everywhere but the edges". Dates should always be converted to GMT for processing and storage, numbers and currencies should always be in culture invariant formats. Culture-specificity seems more like a UI/presentation issue to me.

Comment: @JohnBledsoe So where is the edge? TryParse "10,00" when your Culture is Dutch (in this case) should parse 10.00 as a Double.

Comment: The edge is the user interface. You're dealing with intra-application communication ($.ajax to web service), which in my experience should use the invariant culture.